# Add New Table Row after 5 Table Columns with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

From the Title, I have a constantly changing data, which is making the first row of a `HTML` table. The data is coming from the controller and I couldn't make it to come to the next row after 5 columns are loaded. So Far, my code is as follows:-

```
<?php
foreach($folder_info as $show)
   {
    echo '<table><tr>';
    echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:100px;"></span><br/>'.$show['folder_name'];
    echo '</tr></table>';
   } 
?>
```

Anyone can offer me a help would be appreciated

Comment: Have JQuery `GET` the data and the use `insertAfter` (or similar) available JQuery function to insert a row

Comment: @AhsN, I just came to know about insertAfter, I will try! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want jQuery to insert content like "`<tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td>.... </tr>`" that's easier done if the table has an addressable ID, let's say `"<table id='myTable'>"`, now with jQuery you can go:  `$("#myTable tr:last").after(rowContent);`  where the var "rowContent" is the html of the new row you're inserting.